# HTML+CSS: Scrolling inside a div taking remaining screen height

Tags: html, css

How can I make a table **in** a div (that takes the remaining screen height) scrollable without scrolling the whole page?

I know how to make it scrollable inside the div by wrapping it like this

```
    <div style="overflow: auto; height: 300px;">
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
```

but how can I make the div's height use all of the remaining screen height?

EDIT: here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading<button class="pull-right" onclick="myFunction();">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body row" id="filter" style="display: none; padding-top: 0;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-sm-6 column" style="height: auto; margin-top: 1em">
            <!-- filter selector -->
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Table -->
        <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: auto; height: 300px;">
            <table class="table">
            ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById('filter');
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would get help if you share some code so that other members will not have to guess what is going on. Thanks

Comment: Did you use `height: 100vh` before? use it maybe helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use **vh** instead **%** : **[100vh] vertical height**
>
> i set width **90%**, you can change it.
>
> table is always **center** because `div.parent` is `margin: 0 auto`

```css
     .parent {
            background-color: #ccc;
            width: 90%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 0 auto
        }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="parent">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Column heading</th>
                    <th>Column heading</th>
                    <th>Column heading</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                    <td>Column content</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with the overview, you can do the following

```
<div style="
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: n%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

I'm leaving it on the `right` and I use the `border-left` so you can see that you need a reasonable `width`

EDIT: for edit html

you set parent tag `position` property with `relative`.

You using `position: absolute;` for `div` tag

Answer (score 1):

use [viewport percentages](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) but it will not affect old ie.

```
height: 100vh;
```